# Как сделать с помощью стрелки раздел меню

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, svg

Как сделать  с помощью стрелки раздел меню без `CSS border tricks`.

Я хочу сделать панель навигации меню с несколькими `inline-block`  элементами `li`, каждый из которых должен иметь правую сторону в форме стрелки. Похожую на это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сделал поиск для этого, и самый распространенный ответ - использовать трюки `css` с `transparent border`. Как этот:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jx99z/5/)

```css
.text {
    background-color:#ff0000;
    color:#fff;
    display:inline-block;
    padding-left:4px;
}
.arrow {
    border-style: dashed;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-width: 0.20em;
    display: -moz-inline-box;
    display: inline-block;
    /* Use font-size to control the size of the arrow. */
    font-size: 100px;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 0;
    background-color:#fff; /* change background color acc to bg color */ 
    border-left-width: 0.2em;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-color: #ff0000;
    left:0.25em;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">Some Text<span class="arrow"></span></div>
```

Другое решение, которое я нашел, состоит в том, что я могу рисовать любой элемент, используя `svg`.

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OXWoXd)

```css
svg polygon {
    fill: transparent;
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 2px;
}

svg {
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 50%; 
}

body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: .2em; 
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <polygon points="
    0,0 
    0,200
    270,200
    300,100
    270,0
    150,0
    " />
<div>Item 1</div>
</svg>
```

Но это решение еще хуже: каким-то образом я не могу сделать элемент шире, чем 300 px, и посмотреть на эти уродливые границы и фон. Кроме того, я хочу, чтобы этот бар был отзывчивым. Благодарю!

Перевод вопроса: [How to make a div with arrow like side without css border tricks? @Artur Miller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38036998/7394871)

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38036998/how-to-make-a-div-with-arrowlike-side-without-css-border-tricks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body {
  font: normal normal 30px sans-serif;
}

.bc {
  margin: 1em;
}

.bc span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 3em;
  line-height: 3em;
}

.bc span {
  color: black;
  padding: 0 1em;
}

.bc span::after,
.bc span::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1.5em;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: skewX(30deg);
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.bc span:not(:last-child)::after,
.bc span:not(:last-child)::before {
  border-right: none;
}

.bc span::after {
  top: 50%;
  transform: skewX(-30deg);
  border-top: none;
}

.bc span:hover {
  color: white;
}

.bc span:hover::after,
.bc span:hover::before {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.bc span::before {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="bc">
  <span>Lorem ipsum</span><span>Lorem ipsum</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @ Добротная работа, качественно. (+) Можно добавить еще нюанс, как у иностранного автора "Persijn" изменение цвета активной ссылки

Comment: @Alexandr_T Спасибо. Нет предела совершенству. К сожалению в моем способе есть проблема - трудно сделать левую границу у первого элемента, как в макете.

Comment: в SVG не хотите попробовать? Там с границами проще.

Comment: @Alexandr_T Я хотел как раз альтернативный вариант дать, без SVG

Answer (score 3):

### Svg отлично подходят для создания фигур в html

- Используйте **`polygon element`** для рисования фигур.
- **`Text element`** для  описания ссылки.
- **`A element`** для создания ссылки.

```css
#arrow-menu a polygon {
  fill: #888;
  stroke: #222;
}
#arrow-menu a:hover polygon {
  stroke: #222;
  fill: black;
}
#arrow-menu a:hover text {
  fill: cornflowerblue;
}
#arrow-menu a {
  font-size: 5px;
}
```

```html
<svg id="arrow-menu" viewBox="-1 -1 112 22" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <a xlink:href="#">
    <polygon points="0,0 20,0 25,10 20,20 0,20 0,0"></polygon>
    <text x="1.5" y="11.5">Menu link</text>
  </a>
  <a xlink:href="#">
    <polygon transform="translate(22)" points="0,0 20,0 25,10 20,20 0,20 5,10 0,0"></polygon>
  </a>
  <a xlink:href="#">
    <polygon transform="translate(44)" points="0,0 20,0 25,10 20,20 0,20 5,10 0,0"></polygon>
  </a>
  <a xlink:href="#">
    <polygon transform="translate(66)" points="0,0 20,0 25,10 20,20 0,20 5,10 0,0"></polygon>
  </a>
</svg>
```

Перевод ответа: [How to make a div with arrowlike side without css border tricks? @Persijn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38038730/7394871)